# selenium if test fail mvn build also fail

Tags: maven, build, testng, assert

I have written some code:

```java
 @Test
    public void test2() {
        Assert.assertEquals(12,13,"its not match");
    }
}
```

When I run `mvn clean test`, build and test both fail. 
I googled and found that I needed to add `maven-surefire-plugin` but I have already added it to my pom.

and here this is my **pom.xml**

```xml
  <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0-alpha-3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-failsafe-plugin -->


    </dependencies>

    <build>

        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>/home/ghost/New_lifeQA/learn/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: consider posting the logs of the error